# How to list and navigate to tables in Texstudio

Tags: texstudio, editors

Is there an option of navigating to tables from the "structure" list in Texstudio. In LED, which I used before, there was a similar structure list with all figures and tables listed under the name of section. I now that in Texstudio I can navigate by labels, but as all labels are listed together, it is not very convenient.

Kuba

Answer (score 1):

No. Information on figures and tables is not tracked in TeXstudio.